# Linking one table to each user in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a Django project where I need to link one table(model) to each user.
Assume MyTable_1 maps to user_1 and so on.

The primary key for MyTable will be a DateField which contains continuous dates from the time user signed-up.

```
 MyTable_1 for User_1

|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| Date(PK)  | food_ate | game_played |    ran_today    |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| 10/01/20  |  rice    |    chess    |       Yes       |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| 11/01/20  |sandwhich |   tennis    |       No        |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|

 MyTable_2 for User_2

|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| Date(PK)  | food_ate | game_played |    ran_today    |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| 16/03/19  |  pizza   |    rugby    |       Yes       |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|
| 17/03/19  |  pasta   |   football  |       Yes       |
|-----------|----------|-------------|-----------------|

 And so on for every new user created. User logs in those information in MyTable.
```

How can I implement this? I am using PostgreSQL and have written custom User Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need seperate *tables* just seperate *rows*.

A ForeignKey relation will do the trick, something like this in your models.py:

```
# user model:
User(models.Model, ...):
    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    ...


# log model:
Log(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    date = models.DateField(...)
    food_ate = models.CharField(...)
    game_played = models.CharField(...)
    ran_today = models.CharField(...)

    class Meta: unique_together = ('user', 'date',)
```

Then, elsewhere, you can access your users' logs like so:

```
user = User.objects.get(id='the_user_id')
logs = user.logs.all()
```

Comment: I thought of this. Wouldn't this just create 1 row for each user in the "Log" table? But how do I store information date-wise?

Comment: I added the date-field, you can add a Meta class to ensure there is only one date and user combination per log. The ForeignKey on the Log model means one User can have many Logs but each Log can only have one user.

Comment: Okay got it! So what Django will do is create a new table for every date, right? And what if my data grows over many years. Wouldn't that affect performance?

Comment: It's still a single table for the 'Log' model - but if it helps you can certainly think of it as seperate tables. And the short answer is yes, it will affect performance, but with the right infrastructure you should never need to worry about it.

Comment: I studied about the "unique_together" option. At the database level, it would be too complicated with many users over a long time. Is it possible to create one table for a user?

Comment: Or I could create one model each for my attributes(food_ate, game_played ...) since they are few. And then I could use columns for users and rows for dates. Can I implement this in Django? If yes, could you provide me resources for help?